# Redirect to another page using php and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have two pages one for filling data and other one for initializing data I am sending the filled data via post method using ajax, I want to redirect the user from initializing page, i used simple `header("Location: somelocation");` in the initialize page but it seems it does not work this way and it just sends the html value of the target page using ajax (I checked it with firebug),so what is the alternatives here ? should i use ajax it self for the redirection part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return your location via json response, for example {"location": "somelocation"}, and then handle it in ajax success callback and go to page you need:

> document.location.href = somelocation

Answer (score 0):

You should use javascript for the redirection, not ajax.

When your ajax request has completed successfully you should then do a `window.location = 'new/path/to/some/location';`

Using the header("Location: ...") in your destination PHP script (the one that receives the data) will only return to you the html in the ajax response body, but not interpret it.

Comment: it has to be in a specific time which i am checking it in the page(the one that receive data ) i should use jscirpt in that page?

Comment: I don't know if I understood. Javascript has to be used in the first page (where you have the form and you are sending the data via ajax). Maybe you could add a little more code so we can explain better.

Comment: i have 100 group of radio buttons i put an event handler on it to send the form data using post to second page when any changes occur  to the form but till specific time which i am doing it server side

Comment: So you don't want to do the redirection after every ajax call. Nice. Then you should do what iSunRise suggested, read the ajax response content, and then "decide" whether you want to do the redirect or not.